# Create partition on Debian and affect /var

Tags: partition

I need to affect /var to a new partition. Do I just need to add a line to fstab file and reboot??

My fstab:

```
/dev/md1    /   ext4    errors=remount-ro,relatime,discard  0   1
/dev/md2    /data   ext4    defaults,relatime   0   2
/dev/sda3   none    swap    defaults    0   0
/dev/sdb3   none    swap    defaults    0   0
/dev/md0    /home   ext4    defaults,relatime,discard   0   2
proc        /proc   proc    defaults        0   0
sysfs       /sys    sysfs   defaults        0   0
tmpfs       /dev/shm    tmpfs   defaults    0   0
devpts      /dev/pts    devpts  defaults    0   0
```

I'm not sur how to o that, if you could help me, thanks.

Comment: There is the "Hard disk upgrade Mini HOWTO" that should teach you everything you need to know about moving filesystems to new disks/partitions/LVs: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Hard-Disk-Upgrade/

Comment: thanks, but this link talk about a new partition on a new disk. My case is moving a dir on a new partition on the actual disk...

Answer (score 1):

The general procedure for moving (hot) data from one partition to another is:

1. Create the new partition
2. Bring the system to single-user mode
3. Mount the old partition in its normal place ;
   Mount the new partition somewhere like `/mnt`
4. Transfer the data
   (rsync, tar, whatever. Just make sure to preserve permissions and ownership)
5. Unmount both partitions
6. Edit `/etc/fstab` to reflect the new filesystem layout
7. Reboot and verify